# How to avoid caching of input in JavaScript function in bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

JavaScript function inputs seem to be caching the arguments if the value is being used earlier.

### Example

**Use cases**

Find students in schools with a name or with their ages or both together.

**utterance 1**

> find students in the school with the name George.

then in it will invoke the function with (name as George and age as null)

**utterance 2**

> find students in the school with ages 10.

then in it will invoke the function with (name as George and age as 10)

How to avoid caching of the variable name as George in the second case?

Comment: Solved!  This issue by adding `features {
   transient
 }`to concept and for date time expression created customdatetime expression with role of viv.time.DateTimeExpression and added transient to features works

Answer (score 2):

Solved! issue by adding

```
features { 
transient 
}
```

example of text concept

```
text (name) {
  description (name of the person)
  features{
    transient
  }
}
```

For `DateTimeExpression` created `CustomDateTimeExpression` with role-of `viv.time.DateTimeExpression` and added transient to features works.

```
structure (CustomDateTimeExpression) {
 role-of (viv.time.DateTimeExpression)
 description (wrapper for DateTimeExpression)
 features {
 transient
 }
}
```

links: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/text.features